# "We were made/making to leave immediately"

Tags: phrase-usage

I am struggling with the following:

> "We were .....to leave immediately"

Options being here "**making to**" and "**made**".

Cannot both be used to make sense? Only "making to" is marked as correct but I am not sure why. I think that "make sb do sth" would work too, would it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but mean markedly different things.

"Being made to leave" is just a clause in the passive voice; someone is making you leave.

"Making to leave" is an idiom meaning intending and preparing to leave.

Both sound natural in English, and you haven't mentioned any context that would indicate which one is intended, but hopefully the reasoning is now clear.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure about the idiom - the Cambridge dictionary states it is a phrasal verb (make to do sth - If you make to do something, you are just going to do it when something interrupts you:)

Comment: @Markazali Almost true. An interruption is one example of why we might choose to focus on the point in time where someone is "making to leave" instead of just saying they left, but the same reasoning could apply to any concurrent event.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct, but they have quite different meanings.

"We were made to leave immediately" means we were compelled to leave immediately.

"We were making to leave immediately" means we were acting as if we were leaving immediately. Possibly we were hoping to be asked to stay, but we were not showing that.